# C++ overloading == operator example

Tags: operator-overloading, c++14

making chess game and i can't overload `==` operator (think that is problem, ofc  if i added correctly elements in array).

```
enum squerState{EMPTY, ROOK, KNIGHT, BISHOP, QUEEN, KING, PAWN};

class Board
{
public:
Board();
~Board();

friend bool operator==(const Board& lhs, const Board& rhs);

squerState stanjePolja;
squerColor bojaPolja;
pieceColor bojaFigurice;

Board* board[8][8];
};
```

**//.ccp**

```
Board* piece;
for(int x= 0; x < 8; x++)
{
     for(int y=0; y < 8; y++)
    {
    piece->stanjePolja = squerState::ROOK;
    piece->bojaPolja = squerColor::WHITE;
    piece->bojaFigurice = pieceColor::BLACK_PIECE;

    board[y][x] = piece;
    }
}
```

**//overload ==**

```
bool operator==(const Board& lhs, const Board& rhs)
{
    return lhs.stanjePolja == rhs.stanjePolja;

}
```

**//Draw test board**

```
void Board::drawBoard()
{
    for (auto y = 0; y < 8; y++)
    {
        for (auto x = 0; x < 8; x++)
        {
            if (board[y][x] == squerState::ROOK)
            {
                std::cout << 'O';
            }
            else
                std::cout << 'X';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Problem is when i try to draw test board with ROOK's.

```
if (board[y][x] == squerState::ROOK)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
if (board[y][x] == squerState::ROOK)
```

it looks like the type of the expression on the left-hand side is `Board*`, but the type of expression on the right-hand side is `enum squerState`. You did not define an equals operator for those types and they can't be compared by other means.

You probably want your `Board` class to contain an array of `SquareState` instances.

```
enum Piece { None, Pawn, ... };
enum Color { Black, White };

struct SquareState
{
     Piece piece_;
     Color color_;
};

struct Board
{
    void drawBoard() const;
    SquareState board_[8][8];
};

void Board::drawBoard() const
{
     for( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
     {
          for( int j = 0; j < 8; ++j )
          {
               switch( board_[ i ][ j ].piece_ )
               {
                    case Piece::None:
                        std::cout << " ";
                        break;
                    case Piece::Pawn:
                        std::cout << "P";
                        break;
                    // ...
               }
          }
          std::cout << std::endl;
     }
}
```

I hope this helps.